# Awk unix making multiple lines into one and extracting words

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I need to extract the lease IP "192.168.21.100", hardware ethernet "14:10:9f:f2:1d:00" and client-hostname "2015cmoran-2".

And it needs to be in one line like this

"192.168.21.100", "14:10:9f:f2:1d:00", "2015cmoran-2"

```
lease 192.168.21.100 {
 starts 4 2017/03/02 05:43:15;
 ends 4 2017/03/02 17:43:15;
 cltt 4 2017/03/02 05:43:15;
 binding state active;
 next binding state free;
 rewind binding state free;
 hardware ethernet 14:10:9f:f2:1d:00;
 uid "\001\024\020\237\362\035\000";
 client-hostname "2015cmoran-2";
 } 
server-duid "\000\001\000\001 IL\264x\243Q\031O\032";
```

I have done these but I don't think this is the right way to do it

```
cat /var/dhcpd.leases | sed 's/;//g' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;++I) if ($I == "client-hostname") {print $2};}' 

cat /var/dhcpd.leases | sed 's/;//g' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;++I) if ($I == "ethernet") {print $3};}'
```

Comment: The `cat | sed` and `sed | awk` are both variants of the common antipattern [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).  You should need zero occurrences of `cat` unless you are specifically concatenating multiple input files, and rarely more than one of `grep`, `sed`, or Awk in the same pipeline.

Comment: `cat /var/dhcpd.leases | sed 's/;//g' | sed 's/"//g'` can be written as `sed 's/[;"]//g' /var/dhcpd.leases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=$(awk -v ORS="," '/lease/||/hardware ethernet/||/client-hostname/{gsub(/{|\;|\"/,"");print "\""$NF"\"" }' inputfile|sed -r 's/(^.*),/\1/' )


 echo $x
 "192.168.21.100","14:10:9f:f2:1d:00","2015cmoran-2"
```

This will filter down the lines which contain `lease||hardware ethernet||client-hostname` , then `gsub` would be used to filter out characters like `{|}|;|"` . Once this is done print the lines. Note that `ORS` is modified to comma. `sed` is used to weed out last comma sign coming from `ORS`.